# SMS from amazon service to user's mobile number

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

Can we send a SMS to a mobile number through amazon service? I need to send a plain message and not notifications.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) can't send SMS messages to recipients who have not opted-in to receive topic notifications.

The SMS capability in SNS is limited to users who respond affirmatively to the initial message requesting that they confirm their subscription to a topic -- for notifications.